# Div spanning 100% height of the browser and zooming

Tags: html, css, height, zooming

```
body, html{
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#wrapper_with_fancy_bg_that_blends_into_bodys_bg{
    height: 100%; 
    min-height: 100%; 
}
```

It is emberassing, but I can't figure out how to fight with getting this when zooming in and then scrolling down:

[image: height 100% doesnt work when zoomed in]
    _

The only solution I've come up with is setting div's height to the height of body on window resize. Is there any way to do make div actually span 100% of body height no matter what with plain css?

Comment: it only appears on zooming in and scrolling down as stated

Comment: also I can't use min-height with a specific value in this case because the content is variable

Comment: Please reproduce your problem over at [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) and clarify what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
html, body { 
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0; 
    height: 100%; 
}  

#wrapper_with_fancy_bg_that_blends_into_bodys_bg {  
    min-height: 100%;
    height:auto !important;  
    height:100%; 
    overflow: hidden !important;
    /* your fancy background here */
}
```

Here is an working JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hehUH/1/ or the full view http://jsfiddle.net/hehUH/1/show/